# SFTP user can't edit or create files

Tags: linux, ssh, permissions, sftp, chroot

Server: Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

I am using openSSH and have created an SFTP user called `bob` who belongs to group `sftponly`. I have chrooted bob to his home directory which is `/usr/share/nginx/www/bob/`.

bob is able to SFTP onto the server and view is home directory, however he is unable to edit the files in his directory. I have run `chown -R bob /usr/share/nginx/www/bob/*` to make bob the owner of his files yet he is still unable to edit them.

Why would this be?

Comment: I don't mind being downvoted but please tell me why - do you need more information .etc? I'm very new to server admin and it doesn't help my confusion much.

Comment: Chroot SFTP is a pain. I've been dealing with the same types of issues the past week.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To properly chroot an sftponly group member, you need to set this options in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
Subsystem       sftp    internal-sftp
Match Group sftponly
        ChrootDirectory /srv/chroot/%u
        ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

It is a requirement that the home directory, and the directories all the way up to the root of the system, of chrooted users must belong to `root:root`

Given the following values for a user:

```
$ id user001
uid=1003(user001) gid=1003(user001) groups=1006(sftponly)
$ grep user001 /etc/passwd
user001:x:1003:1003::/input:/sbin/nologin
```

You need a directory structure like this one:

```
$ tree /srv/chroot
/srv/chroot
├── user001
│   └── input
```

Because user001's HOME directory is evaluated after the chroot call, he/she lands in the `input` directory, where write permissions are valid:

```
$ ls -lrtd /srv/chroot/user001/input
drwxrwx--- 2 user001 sftponly 4.0K Apr 07 17:55 /srv/chroot/user001/input
```

Comment: Thanks I had the chroot set up correctly it's just I didn't realise they don't have permissions directly in their chroot directory and need a sub folder. I moved all the files into a sub folder and they can now make changes.