# rbash to limit user to its home directory closes sftp connection

Tags: ssh, redhat, centos6, sftp, rhel6

Server: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5 (Santiago)

Using openssh-server to allow sftp connexions.

I'm trying to limit users to their own personal home directory.
So i modified /etc/passwd setting user "john" to use `/bin/rbash` instead of `/bin/bash`

```
john:502:503::/home/john:/bin/rbash
```

If i do that, john cannot connect via sftp: the connexion closes as soon as he logs in (sftp message is `Connection closed`) .
If i set the bash to /bin/bash instead, his connexion works fine, but then, john can travel all over the server file system using cd.

Can you explain what am I doing wrong in order to limit users connecting via sftp to their own directory?

Comment: Is `/bin/rbash` included in `/etc/shells`?

Comment: no, it is not. I created it using a symlink to /etc/bash.

Comment: I've added it to the shells file. Reloaded sshd. Connexion still closes.

Comment: What does the ssh log show?

Comment: `Feb 26 11:41:08 sshd[10401]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user john by (uid=0)

Feb 26 11:41:08 sshd[10401]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user john`

Comment: I found another question which contains complete instructions for how to chroot in sftp. Could you look at http://serverfault.com/questions/497011/sftp-user-cant-edit-or-create-files - if it is what you need, then I'd like to close this question as a duplicate

Comment: Thank you. If i understand that question's answer, it's not using openssh-server. I have to see the implications of switching to internal-sftp. I'll get back to you in a short while.

Comment: Thank you, it helped. The proposed answer by mr.spuratic did provide a  working solution that i found clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rbash` won't let you run commands with a leading `/`, if that's being attempted then it will simply exit.

Unless you're using the internal sftp-server, an attempt to exec `/usr/libexec/sftp-server` will fail.

Using `Subsystem       sftp    internal-sftp` in the `sshd_config` will fix that.

However, using `rbash` won't stop sftp from wandering around your filesystem, you probably want to [chroot the users instead](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9853/restricting-an-ssh-scp-sftp-user-to-a-directory).

Answer (score 0):

you can use the normal shell without the link, for restrited shell, in /etc/profile put this

```
 if [[ $USER == "pluto" ]]; then
      export PATH=$HOME/bin
      readonly PATH
      set -r
 fi
```

and

```
mkdir /home/pluto/bin as root
ln -s /bin/ls /home/pluto/bin/ls
```

In this way sftp work and pluto can only use the ls command