# CentOS 6.5 ssh ChrootDirectory not working

Tags: ssh, sftp, centos6.5, chroot

I have been trying to configure my CentOS 6.5 minimal 64 bit machine to allow SFTP users to connect and get jailed to specific folders. I can sftp in using the unix commmand: "sftp user@localhost" and move around within the restricted directory, but I can't use LS or any other commands like that. However, the real issue is that I can't connect at all using FileZilla. I simply get this error:

```
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    pwd
Response:   Current directory is: "/"
Command:    ls
Status: Listing directory /
Error:  Unable to open .: permission denied
Error:  Connection timed out after 20 seconds of inactivity
```

I'd love to be able to use LS when using the SFTP command in Unix but most importantly I need it to work with FileZilla.

Here is a description of the current setup:

/etc/ssh/sshd_config

```
Subsystem    sftp    internal-sftp

Match Group sftp_users
    X11Forwarding no
    AllowTcpForwarding no
    ChrootDirectory /var/sftp/%u
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

grep user /etc/passwd

```
user:x:500:500::/var/sftp/user/incoming:/sbin/nologin
```

groups user

```
user : user sftp_users
```

ll / | grep var

```
drwxr-xr-x root root var
```

ll /var | grep sftp

```
drwxr-xr-x root root sftp
```

ll /var/sftp | grep user

```
drwxr-xr-x root root user
```

ll /var/sftp/user

```
drwxrwxr-x user sftp_users incoming
drwxrwxr-x user sftp_users outgoing
```

Everything I've read says that's how it's supposed to be setup, so please let me know what I'm missing. I just can't seem to get it to work properly.

Thanks for your time.

[Edit:]

I used this command to modify my user's home directory;

```
usermod -d /incoming
```

that way he would land in /incoming rather than the full path of the directory as it was previously.

grep user /etc/passwd

```
user:x:500:500::/incoming:/sbin/nologin
```

ls -lrtd /var/sftp/user/incoming

```
drwxrwxr-x user sftp_users /var/sftp/user/incoming
```

sshd_config

```
#Subsystem      sftp    /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
Subsystem       sftp    internal-sftp -f AUTH -l INFO

Match Group sftp_users
        ChrootDirectory /var/sftp/%u
        ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

However, I still get the same errors from using the SFTP command in UNIX and FileZilla on Windows.

I added the debug level logging to the sshd config, but the messages aren't populating in the /var/log/messages file for anyone but the root user. So that route is not working currently. Also the /var/log/secure file doesn't show any errors with the SFTP authentication and session start.

SFTP output

```
[root@...]# sftp user@localhost
Connecting to localhost...
user@localhost's password:
sftp> ls
Couldn't get handle: Permission denied
sftp> cd ..
sftp> cd incoming
Couldn't canonicalise: Permission denied
sftp> quit
[root@...]#
```

Comment: Enable DEBUG log level in `sshd`, restart the service and inspect the login attempt logs.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SFTP user can't edit or create files](http://serverfault.com/questions/497011/sftp-user-cant-edit-or-create-files)