# backup /home over sftp - root

Tags: security, backup, rsync, sftp

My current task is to set up a (remote) backup (using rsync/rsnapshot) over sftp of /home (linux). Obviously some files are read only for the owner (ie -r-------; and should stay that way) so i guess I'll need the root user to back up those files. Setting up an rsync daemon seems also too insecure to me.

However, I do hesitate to use an ssh key for that purpose due to security concerns (if the backup server get's owned the attacker will have direct shells to other servers). I was thinking of creating a backup user with chroot sftp (as suggested [Chroot SFTP - Possible to allow user to write to current (chroot) directory](https://serverfault.com/questions/910789/chroot-sftp-possible-to-allow-user-to-write-to-current-chroot-directory)) but I guess I'd cripple my root user as I would loose shell access :(.

What setup would you suggest?

Comment: it depends on how you want to use the most way. I could think about a cenario where you could use a single user for each user with its own key, and then copy via cronjob on the main server to the correct  destination

Comment: that would work technically, however this solution would not scale (i.e. create a lot of manual effort an maintenance) as I'd lots of keys and lots of crontab edits

Comment: well on one site you will need to have a root shell. on the other side, you can have just one user for all on different sub directories.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Limited SSH access for log retrieval](https://serverfault.com/questions/507878/limited-ssh-access-for-log-retrieval)